# which English usage is more appropriate ''affiliated to/with'' or ''belongs to"?

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

Now I am doing research where its application lies in Engineering and computer science. So, which usage is more appropriate to say: "This research work belongs to Engineering and Computer science" or "This research work is affiliated to Engineering and Computer science" or "This research work is affiliated with Engineering and Computer science"?

Thanks!

Comment: "This research addresses aspects of Engineering and Computer science."

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth Thanks, but here I want to mention my thesis is a part of these fields. I think "This research addresses aspects of...'' doesn't stress the field very well.

Comment: Maybe you can try "pertains to" ?   The word 'affiliated' is most frequently used between peers or subsidiaries. https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/affiliated "Belongs to" claims a possession ...which is a nuanced step beyond connection. This isn't an answer, just a comment. Others might be able to make the point more clearly or correctly.